# discrete_features parameter in sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection

I have a question on the parameters of the mutual_info_classif function as a feature selection method.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif

I have a binomial target Y which takes values (0,1) and X-features of mixed type. The features are binomial (0,1), continuous and categorial.
Within categorial, I have ordinal features (e.g. low, medium, high encoded as 1,2,3) and non-ordinal(e.g. department name which are one-hot encoded).

As I understand, I could set discrete_features = True for my categorical features and discrete_features=False for my numerical (continuous) features.
What does discrete_features = 'auto' mean?  will it treat my continious and ordinal features as dense (False) and the one-hot encoded features as sparse(True)?

Can someone clarify how to set the parameter values in my case?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `discrete_features = 'auto'` , it determines discrete_features = True if the input is sparse. If your input is dense, it treats it as continuous.

For example, if we run your cat features, specifying `discrete_features=True` :

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(111)

target = np.random.binomial(1,0.5,20)
cat_feature = np.random.binomial(3,0.5,(20,2))

mutual_info_classif(cat_feature,target,discrete_features=True)
array([0.03219502, 0.00257154])
```

It's different from specifying it False :

```
mutual_info_classif(cat_feature,target,discrete_features=False)
array([0, 0])
```

Now if use 'auto' its the same as `discrete_features=False` since the input is dense:

```
mutual_info_classif(cat_feature,target,discrete_features='auto')
array([0, 0])
```

We make the input sparse, we get the same output as when we specify `discrete = False` :

```
cat_feature = csr_matrix(cat_feature)

type(cat_feature)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

mutual_info_classif(cat_feature,target,discrete_features="auto")
Out[42]: array([0.03219502, 0.00257154])
```

You have this option because we often onehot encode the categorical features, and a sparse matrix is more suitable given the amount of zeros make .